# VisualStudio search text using regex to find method

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

How should regex looks in Visual Studio search text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>).
I want to find all GetById method invocations where first argument has random name, but second has fixed name : 'transaction'

My examples

```
Sth1.Instance.GetById(formInstanceSessionId, transaction);
Sth2.Instance.GetById(userId, transaction);
Sth3.Instance.GetById(invoiceId, transaction);
```

I have tried the following regex, but it's not working:

```
GetById[(]*[,]\stransaction[)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `\w+` or `[^,()]+` to match those unknown substrings:

```
\bGetById\(\w+,\s*transaction\s*\)
```

[image]

**Details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `GetById\(` -  a literal `GetById(` string
- `\w+` - 1 or more letters, digits, or underscore

   OR
- `[^,()]+` - 1+ chars other than `,`, `(` and `)`
- `,` - a comma
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `transaction` - a literal word
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\)` - a `)` symbol.